# How to partition variance among parameters in a Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: r, statistics

I have some doubts as how to better extract information from a Monte Carlo simulation, I will simplify the problem here, using some R pseudocode but the question is more general.

Let's say I have a function with three parameters, each of them with a mean and SD. For this example I will use normal distributions, but for more general cases let's assume one of them is another distribution.

`f(x,y,z) = rnorm(mean_x, sd_x) *  rnorm(mean_y, sd_y) * rnorm(mean_z, sd_z)`

I am using a Monte Carlo simulation to quantify  the uncertainty, quite straight-forward. I am interested though in understanding what % of the total uncertainty corresponds to each parameter, done computationally and not analytically.

One way I have envisioned would be:

1. Define total uncertainty as the 0.05-0.95 quantiles of the full MC simulation, and this would be 100% of the model uncertainty.
2. Do a new simulation, but now set one parameter fixed using the mean value, such as:

`f(x,y,z) = mean_x *  rnorm(mean_y, sd_y) * rnorm(mean_z, sd_z)`

3. The difference between the "total uncertainty" and the 0.05-0.95 quantiles of this simulation would then be amount of uncertainty related to this specific parameter.
4. Repeat for the other parameters.

I know this is a simplification as it ignores interactions among parameters, but would this be correct? The problem in question is slightly more complex than this so other analytical approaches are not that feasible.

Comment: Why not simply put the results of your simulation through an ANOVA anaysis?  The sum-of-squares associated with each of your parameters, relative to the total sum-of-squares, gives you the proportion of the total variance associated with each parameter.

Comment: That could work... problem is that I have 1.000.000 sites, each with a unique x,y,z and their uncertainties, but I'm only interested in the sum of all the sites. So I was trying to implement something that I could push through the whole calculation. I could do an ANOVA for each site and then look at the average variance, I will explore if it's possible. Thanks!